# Automatically start godoc localhost server in OS X?

Tags: macos, go, godoc

In Go, you can start HTTP server and then browse through the Go document via the specific port. For example, if you type in `godoc -http=:3333` in Terminal, the localhost server starts working on port 3333 and you can then view the official Go document.

However, I would like to make it start automatically whenever I log in to the OS X system, since it is so powerful and convenient to write in Go code with even when I'm off the Wi-Fi connection. So is it feasible to use such daemon in OS X?

I have implemented and utilized the exact functionality in MongoDB from [an example here](http://pragmaticstartup.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/auto-start-mongodb-mac-osx/), and it's exactly this kind of service that I want to achieve...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this in the folder `~/Library/LaunchAgents` with a file name like `org.golang.doc.example.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
           http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.golang.doc.example</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/go/bin/godoc</string>
      <string>-http=:6060</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true />
  </dict>
</plist>
```

You may have to create the folder yourself.

The next time you log into your account, `godoc` should automatically start on port 6060.

(I have not tested it very well though. Feedback welcome!)

Comment: Awesome. This is definitely what I wanted to use, but hit the wall due to my lack of understanding of how to edit a `.plist` file. Thanks a lot. One question: if I want to terminate it temporarily, how can I do that? It looks like even if I `kill` the process, the process automatically restarts immediately. Or does `KeepAlive` key make it restart?

Comment: @user2360798 I am _not_ a `launchd` expert... You can unload the launchd-plist-file by running `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.golang.doc.example.plist`, you can disable the plist altogether by writing (after the first `<dict>` for example) `<key>Disabled</key> <true />`, or you can stop the "plist" by saying `launchctl stop org.golang.doc.example`. At least in theory, I have not tried all of them.

Comment: `KeepAlive` makes it restart. If the process dies, `launchd` starts it again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Terminal` and type:

   cd /Applications/

   echo "godoc -http=:3333" > start_go_doc

   chmod u+x start_go_doc
2. Open `System Preferences`, `Users & Groups`, YOUR CURRENT USER, `Login Items`, `+`, Select /Application/star_go_doc, `Add`.

DONE.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try Dash (Docs & Snippets) from AppStore. Dash is an API Documentation Browser an d Code Snippet Manager. Offline documentation for a lot of languages and frameworks including Golang.

Comment: I use Dash for its code snippet, but when it comes to reading a document, I prefer viewing it on browser to opening another application, since the browser occupies half of my screen and I don't like to make my window more messy. Thanks for your answer though.